# Nexmo Voice api with websockets and azure cognitive services for speech translations

Tags: websocket, azure-cognitive-services, vonage

I am working on a speech translation using azure cognitive services for speech translation. when a caller calls on nexmo number I am getting it on websockets. I am then using azure speech translation to translate text to speech and write it to the socket for response the nexmo call just disconnects. Here is the code that I am using on web socket:

```
      var configWait = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(_appSettings.azurecognitiveservicespeech_subscriptionkey, "centralus");
            using (var audioOutputStream = AudioOutputStream.CreatePullStream())
            using (var output = AudioConfig.FromStreamOutput(audioOutputStream))
            using (var synthesizer1 = new SpeechSynthesizer(configWait, output))
            using (var resultWait = await synthesizer1.SpeakTextAsync("Please Wait while next representative is available."))
            {
                if (resultWait.Reason == ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted)
                {
                    var ttsAudio = resultWait.AudioData;
                    const int chunkSize = 320;
                    var chunkCount = 1;
                    var offset = 0;

                    var lastFullChunck = ttsAudio.Length < (offset + chunkSize);
                    try
                    {
                        while (!lastFullChunck)
                        {
                            await socket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(ttsAudio, offset, chunkSize), result.MessageType, false, CancellationToken.None);
                            offset = chunkSize * chunkCount;
                            lastFullChunck = ttsAudio.Length < (offset + chunkSize);
                            chunkCount++;
                        }

                        var lastMessageSize = ttsAudio.Length - offset;
                        await socket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(ttsAudio, offset, lastMessageSize), result.MessageType, true, CancellationToken.None);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please be more specific regarding the question you would like to ask.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you're potentially sending an oddly sized chunk of audio at the end of your flow. Not sure where this fits into the whole context of your WebSocket as that's not shared in the question. Here's a bit of code that worked for me for both receiving, and writing back audio:

```cs
while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
{
    byte[] audio;
    while(_audioToWrite.TryDequeue(out audio))
    {
        const int bufferSize = 640;
        for(var i = 0; i + bufferSize < audio.Length; i += bufferSize)
        {
            var audioToSend = audio[i..(i + bufferSize)];
            var endOfMessage = audio.Length > (bufferSize + i);
            await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(audioToSend, 0, bufferSize), WebSocketMessageType.Binary, endOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);
        }                        
    }

    result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

    _inputStream.Write(buffer);
}
```

This is from a slightly modified version of a blog post I wrote on the subject. You can find the source code in [GitHub](https://github.com/slorello89/Speech-to-text-azure-dotnet/blob/master/TranscriptionBlogPostDemo/TranscriptionEngine.cs#L75). This does not use the translation services like you are, just does straight speech to text - but it ought to work roughly the same. You can also take a look at the [blog post](https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2019/12/30/building-a-real-time-net-transcription-service-dr) as well.